# MySQL 5.1.x: Performance improvement in Enterprise edition Vs community edition

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

My application is running on MySQL 5.1.58 community edition. 
I tried to search enterprise edition of MySQL 5.1.X but only MySQL 5.6.X version of enterprise edition is available.
Is it possible to download MySQL 5.1.x enterprise edition - trial version? I want to compare the performance testing with the community edition of MySQL 5.1.X

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the only difference between enterprise and community edition is, that the first includes support while the other doesn't.

Comment: From where can I download the MySQL 5.1 enterprise edition?

Comment: See [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69092/mysql-community-edition-capacity/69120?noredirect=1#comment124828_69120) thread - Aleksandr Kuzminsky says they're the same. As has been pointed out, what you get with EE is support and various add-ons, but the core server is the same. Try 5.6 and see if that addresses your perfomance issues. What are they?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get a MySQL Enterprise edition for v5.1.X version.

You can see the diffrence in performance between Community and Enterprise version here:

http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/scalability.html

You can also download Enterprise product guide whitepaper to know more details.

In summary additional features in MySQL Enterprise version are `MySQL Thread Pool`, `MySQL Enterprise audit` and a `Technical support` for your server related issues.