# MySQL Community Edition Capacity

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5, amazon-rds

I am using MySQL Community Edition on Amazon RDS service. It is a very large database, 2/3 tables has about 10 millions records and 4-5 tables has 7-8 millions records.

## Questions

- How much capacity does MySQL Community Edition have?
- Should I have to purchase MySQL Enterprise Edition for my application?
- Where can I get pricing information for the same?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with capacity? If you mean database sizes, there is no limit.

Comment: @ypercube, I mean to say capability to handle workload. Currently, some of my queries includes multiple tables getting very slow (this tables are well normalized and properly indexed as per EXPLAIN)

Comment: In most of databases/workload I've ever seen hardware was the limiting factor, not MySQL itself.

Answer (score 1):

The server core is similar (identical?) on the GA and Standard Edition (SE)/Entreprise Edition (EE). What you're getting with SE/EE is stuff like (from [here](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/))

```
MySQL Partitioning
MySQL Enterprise Backup
MySQL Enterprise Monitor
MySQL Enterprise HA
MySQL Enterprise Scalability
MySQL Enterprise Security
MySQL Enterprise Audit
```

You also get support and some access to goodies on Oracle's MOS (My Oracle Support, used to be Metalink). You can tell your PHB - "look, if anything goes wrong, at least *_you_* won't be blamed!".

The funny thing is that many of these "enterprise" solutions are available from open source contributors in various guises, and I for one am convinced that it's possible to have at least an entreprise standard setup using only Open Source components. With the advent of [WebScaleSQL](http://webscalesql.org/), that situation could move up to  carrier grade.

As for pricing - see [here](http://www.mysql.com/products/), it's basically $2.000 (Standard), $5.000 (Enterprise) or $10.000 (Carrier grade) per year. See the features table for a comparison.

Comment: Community and Enterprise editions are identical indeed.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to capacity, all your constraints start with Amazon RDS, not MySQL. Why ?

I have posts about MySQL in Amazon RDS

- `Aug 02, 2012` : [Local database vs Amazon RDS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21914/local-database-vs-amazon-rds/21919#21919)
- `Oct 12, 2012` : [When should I think about upgrading our RDS MySQL instance based on memory usage?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25840/when-should-i-think-about-upgrading-our-rds-mysql-instance-based-on-memory-usage/25870#25870)
- `Feb 26, 2013` : [MySQL optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35447/mysql-optimization/35455#35455)

Your main bottlenecks for RDS are

- Transaction Log size (always 128M and immutable across all server models)
- Maximum number of connections (set per server model)
- Buffer Pool Size (set per server model)

Either go to EC2 or bare metal server. That way you can be a little more liberal in configuring MySQL.

You should go with MySQL Community version thereafter.